# After xfs repair, only files from root user are accessible

Tags: raid

After a power failure during server installation of CentOS, the external storage system that contains user data could not be mounted due to failed superblocks. I performed an xfs_repair on the system, which worked fine, but only the directories that are owned by root appear after the file system is mounted.

The file system is a Dell MD3200 with 4 LUNS that are assembled in raid 0 via mdadm. Prior to the power outage, the LUNS were detected as /dev/dm-0, /dev/dm-1, etc. After the xfs_repair they appear as /dev/sd* instead as the LUNS are no longer recognized as virtual disks (generated by Dell MDSA).

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: For future reference, you can flag for mod attention to move comments to chat. Cleared them since half the conversation was manually deleted

Comment: @Daneera For future reference, when you are faced with a problem in your disks higher layers, you could take a **snapshot** in the `Dell MD3200` virtual disks. The snapshot does **not** use any space, just keeps things as they are, all modifications then go to a separate place. If the "fix" does not work, just roll-back the snapshot, done, no damage. If the "fix" works, convert the snapshot to "actual" disk. Also, a snapshot is a way to separate changes "from this point on". Get familiar with it, is a extremely useful tool already available for you in the hardware. Good luck.